# Convertir de varchar a decimal SQLITE

Tags: sqlite

Tengo un problema al querer convertir mi dato varchar 3,90000 a decimal 3.90000

Probe con cast(promo_porc as numeric(5,4)) me convierte a 3, no muestra los decimales
Probe tambien cast(promo_poc as float) y tambien me convierte a 3

Alguna forma de hacerlo?

Answer (score 0):

El problema parece la coma (`,`), SQLite debe estar con la localización en inglés, cambia a '.' el separador decimal en el varchar y debería funcionar:

Este es tu caso:

```
sqlite> select cast('3,9' as float)
   ...> ;
3.0
```

Si aplicas un `replace` lo tendrías:

```
sqlite> select cast(replace('3,9', ',','.') as float);
3.9
```

Comment: Me funciono! muchas gracias

Comment: Genial, por favor, si te resultó util la respuesta márcala como aceptada, eso ayudará a otros usuarios.